# Arch Linux OpenVPN DNS-Problem

Tags: arch-linux, openvpn

I can´t successfully connect with OpenVPN or maybe I´ll connect successfully and something is wrong with my network-settings...

this is the Output of OpenVPN while connecting:

```
Thu Feb 13 23:21:13 2014 OpenVPN 2.3.2 x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu [SSL
(OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [eurephia] [MH] [IPv6] built on Nov 13 2013
Thu Feb 13 23:21:13 2014 WARNING: file
'/home/mak/openvpn-config/mkirchweger.p12' is group or others
accessible Thu Feb 13 23:21:13 2014 Attempting to establish TCP
connection with [AF_INET]83.164.xxx.xx:xxxx [nonblock] Thu Feb 13
23:21:14 2014 TCP connection established with
[AF_INET]83.164.xxx.xx:xxxx Thu Feb 13 23:21:14 2014 TCPv4_CLIENT link
local: [undef] Thu Feb 13 23:21:14 2014 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote:
[AF_INET]83.164.xxx.xx:xxxx Thu Feb 13 23:21:14 2014
[bricks.softpoint.at] Peer Connection Initiated with
[AF_INET]83.164.xxx.xx:xxxx Thu Feb 13 23:21:17 2014 TUN/TAP device
tun0 opened Thu Feb 13 23:21:17 2014 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0,
tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0 Thu Feb 13 23:21:17 2014 /usr/bin/ip
link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500 Thu Feb 13 23:21:17 2014 /usr/bin/ip
addr add dev tun0 local 10.10.x.xx peer 10.10.x.xx Thu Feb 13 23:21:19
2014 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

**UPDATE:**
I´m pretty sure it as an DNS-Issue, ping via IP works but Hostnames can´t be resolved...

Comment: You look to be successfully connected. What is the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: What are the permissions on `/home/mak/openvpn-config/mkirchweger.p12` ?

Comment: I think it is an DNS-Problem the Hostnames can´t be resolved...

Comment: Then please post more about your network settings, especially DNS part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this Github-Repo and now it works :-)

https://github.com/masterkorp/openvpn-update-resolv-conf

when I add this to my openvpn-client config

```
# This updates the resolvconf with dns settings
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf.sh
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf.sh
```